# Debian 11 fresh install boots into grub

Tags: debian, grub, debian-installer

I’m brand new to all of this Linux stuff. I installed Debian 11.5 on my iMac using a bootable thumb drive and at the end, when it said installation successful, i pressed continue to boot into Debian. It booted into grub. When I tried “boot” in grub it said that the kernel must be loaded. What? The only help I found online was to use “ls” and set root and a bunch of other steps but I know that can’t be the best way. What am I missing? Doesn’t Debian install to be ready to boot?